# fs.writeSync output string as an int array

Tags: json, node.js, filesystems

I use express router to catch a ajax post data, which is a stringified JSON obj:

```
router.all('/ajax/setup/save/asset', function (req, res) {   
    console.log('POST: /ajax/setup/save/asset');

    var fileName = path.join(jsonFileNamePrefix, jsonFileName_asset);   

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('POST: DATA: ' + chunk);
        fd = fs.openSync(fileName, 'w');        
        console.log('Opened file: ' + fileName);                                                
        fs.writeSync(fd, chunk);            
        console.log('Wrote ' + chunk + ' into file ' + fileName);
        fs.closeSync(fd);
        console.log('Closed file: ' + fileName);
        res.end();
        console.log('res.end()');
    });         
});
```

Then the console logs:

```
POST: /ajax/setup/save/asset
POST: DATA: {"asset":"test"}
Opened file: /srv/data/asset.json
Wrote {"asset":"test"} into file /srv/data/asset.json
Closed file: /srv/data/asset.json
res.end()
```

However, the file is actually written as:

```
[123,34,97,115,115,101,116,34,58,34,116,101,115,116,34,125]
```

Tried telling fs.writeSync to use 'utf8', 'hex' encoding, still got same result.
Also tried JSON.parse and then JSON.stringify the incoming data chunk, didn't help either..

Comment: The `chunk` might be a buffer object. Try `fs.writeSync(fd, chunk.toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `req` object in your code is actually an instance of the `http.IncomingMessage` stream.

When it provides information via the `data` event, this information is provided as a buffer.

Additionally, not all the data for the request is guaranteed to be available in the first call to the handler.

There are several ways to capture this data into a useable string. You could create a new string and simply concat the chunks together

```
router.all('/ajax/setup/save/asset', function (req, res) {   
    var buf = ''

    req.on('data', function(chunk){
        buf += chunk.toString();
    });

    req.on('end', function(){
       console.log(buf);
    });
});
```